# can virtual types be used as cronjob instances

Tags: magento2, crontab, virtualtype

I tried to use a virtual type in cronjob as instance but without any success. When I use a real class it works as expected. Is there any hint to get virtual types working in cronjobs?

crontab.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="mygroup">
        <job name="myjob" instance="Vendor\Package\MyClass" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Vendor\Package\Model\VirtualLoggerHandler" type="Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="fileName" xsi:type="string">/var/log/virtual.log</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="Vendor\Package\Model\VirtualLogger" type="Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">virtual</argument>
            <argument name="handlers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="debug" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Package\Model\VirtualLoggerHandler</item>
                <item name="error" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Package\Model\VirtualLoggerHandler</item>
                <item name="critical" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Package\Model\VirtualLoggerHandler</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="Vendor\Package\MyClass" type="Vendor\Package\BaseClass" shared="true">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logger" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Package\Model\VirtualLogger</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Comment: Please share the code which you have  tried

Comment: added code examples

Comment: I know it's kind of old, but I wansn't able to get this working. I end up in virtual type hell. CLI commands as virtual types work flawlessly, crons not so much and I have no idea why. For some reason, the arguments that are also virtual types of the main cron virtual type don't get processed anymore.

Answer (score 3):

So I did a little more digging.
The result is that the virtual types work nicely for cron configuration. The problem for me what that I was configuring the virtual types wrong.

Here is my cron configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="import_simple_products" instance="ImportSimpleProductsCron" method="execute">
            <schedule>10 3 * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

and the di.xml contains this:

```
<virtualType name="ImportSimpleProductsCron" type="[Vendor]\Import\Cron\Import">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="processFactory" xsi:type="object">SimpleProductsProcessFactory</argument><!-- also virtual type -->
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<virtualType name="SimpleProductsProcessFactory" type="[Vendor]\Import\Model\Import\ProcessInterfaceFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="instanceName" xsi:type="string">SimpleProductsProcess</argument><!-- also virtual type -->
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<virtualType name="SimpleProductsProcess" type="[Vendor]\Import\Model\Import\Process">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">simple</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Comment: can be this used as well for event observer instance?

Comment: @AntonioPedicini I did not try it, but I assume yes. For the same reason. Observer classes are instantiated via Object manager which knows about virtual types

Comment: that worked thanks.